# how to call a function inside if else statement in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code for a jquery message box. If I click on the following link a message box appears.

```
<p><a id="msgup" class="">Demo Top</a></p>
<script>
    $("#msgup").bar({
        color            : '#1E90FF',
        background_color : '#FFFFFF',
        removebutton     : false,
        message          : 'Your profile customization has been saved!',
        time             : 2000
    }); 
</script>
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is show the message box when I get "cold" as value in my ajax server response. To achieve this I have tried the following code. but its not working. May be because it is failing to call the jquery function. Could you please how to make it work?

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>contents/hello",
    data: "id="+a_href,
    success: function(server_response) {
        if (server_response == 'cold') {

        //Beginning of the code for message box
        $("#msgup").bar({
            color            : '#1E90FF',
            background_color : '#FFFFFF',
            removebutton     : false,
            message          : 'Your profile customization has been saved!',
            time             : 2000
        });
        //End of the code for message box

        // Instead of the message box code I have tried 
        // alert('Message'); and it worked
        }                       
        else {
            $("#result").html(server_response);
        }               
    }                              
}); //$.ajax ends
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `NULL` and empty `''` string is different, what is `server_response` that you get actually?

Comment: Hi, please check my question again. I have edited my post. Instead of NULL and "" I have used "cold". thanks.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I may be because of failing to call function. Where is `jquery.bar` from?

Comment: Jquery.bar is from external source. (example: `<script src="mysource"></script>`) To see the demo of the message box please check this link http://tympanus.net/Development/jbar/  I have downloaded the plugin from there. Thanks :)

Comment: @bitoshi.n Thanks. Codecandies has solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#msgup").bar(…)
```

binds a click event to #msgup (just guessing), so callin' it from within the ajax code won't help. One possible way to achieve your goal would be initializing $.bar and triggering a click from the ajax code, maybe this way:

```
<p><a id="msgup" class="">Demo Top</a></p>
<script>
    $("#msgup").bar({
        color            : '#1E90FF',
        background_color : '#FFFFFF',
        removebutton     : false,
        message          : 'Your profile customization has been saved!',
        time             : 2000
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>contents/hello",
        data: "id="+a_href,
        success: function(server_response){
            if (server_response == 'cold'){
                //Beginning of the code for message box
                $("#msgup").click();
                //End of the code for message box
           } else {
              $("#result").html(server_response);}                   
           }
        }                             
    });   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `alert()` or `console.log()` in your success function. Call `alert(server_response)`. Or even, `alert(typeof(server_response))`. You can also see if the AJAX is coming back properly by adding an error: condition (with it's own function call just like success:).

My guess is you'll want to check instead of '', for the literal 'null' or even the object null, provided it's getting into the success function.

if (server_response == '' || server_response == 'null' || server_response == null || typeof(server_response) == 'undefined') {...

Once you find out how you expect it to come back, you can use just the check(s) you need.

Comment: Yes the ajax is working fine. The problem is with the message box. I cannot make it work inside the if else statement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping it in a setTimeout(function() { $("#msgup").bar({}); }, 100); to see if it's a timing isssue? If so, instead of putting it in the success:, perhaps put it in complete:?

Also, if you put an alert inside the if(), and it's called, then is the HTML element with the ID #msgup present at that time (again, back to the timing consideration).

Comment: Now it makes sense... for when you say, "If I click on the following link a message box appears." Then a .click() makes perfect sense. I was under the impression calling your .bar() directly worked in any case except inside the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `jquery.bar.js`, `$("#msgup").bar(…)` is just initialize element `"#msgup"` for click event binding. If click event is fired, the `jquery.bar` plug in will create new element and show it as message box. So, you need to fire click event.
Try this

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>contents/hello",
    data: "id="+a_href,
    success: function(server_response) {
        if (server_response == 'cold') {

        //Beginning of the code for message box
        $("#msgup").bar({
            color            : '#1E90FF',
            background_color : '#FFFFFF',
            removebutton     : false,
            message          : 'Your profile customization has been saved!',
            time             : 2000
        });
        $("#msgup").click(); //fire click event
        //End of the code for message box

        // Instead of the message box code I have tried 
        // alert('Message'); and it worked
        }                       
        else {
            $("#result").html(server_response);
        }               
    }                              
}); //$.ajax ends
```